# Count words and spaces with a multiple line text

Tags: python, count, counter, words

I need to count the number of words and the number of spaces of the text indicated below through defining a function in Python. I tried with the `split(" ")` command but due to the text are in two different lines I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help me?

`text1 = "A sentence is a group of words that makes complete sense, \n
 contains a main verb, and begins with a capital letter."`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: @ChristianDean there's no newline in the example...

Comment: @ChristianDean `'1\n3 2'.split()` results in `['1', '3', '2']`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @alfasin Yes, I realize that. I was just going of what the OP said.

Comment: @Bahrom Yep, sorry about that. That was brain-burp there.

Comment: Also see the string method [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

words

```
print len(text1.replace('\\', '').split())
```

spaces

```
print text1.count(' ')
```

Comment: err, the backslash replacement is a remnant of the old version of the question. It's not useful anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Nevertheless, in the case to count the spaces, it is not necessary to specify Python not to count spaces in the first line just after \n?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Another way to count the number of words it's the following:

print len(text1.split())